# Transitions stop working with fullpage.js

Tags: css-transitions, fullpage.js

I added fullpage.js to my project and my css transitions stopped working.

I analyzed the code using code inspector to see, if the classes have been removed or if the transitions have been overwritten but I can't find something. It looks like I don't have naming issues with my classes, as well.

My transitions are simple. I have a class like

```
.element {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
.element-animated {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Then a little bit of jQuery to active the animation on load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.element').addClass('element-animated');
});
```

When adding `$('#fullpage').fullpage();` to my code, my transitions stop working. When I remove it, they work again.

My architecture looks like:

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
    <div class="element2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [fullpage.js faqs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions) you'll it is recommended to fire those actions on the `afterRender` callback:

> **Short answer:** if you are using options such as `verticalCentered:true` or `overflowScroll:true` in fullPage.js initialization, or even horizontal slides, then you will have to treat your selectors as dynamic elements and use delegation. (by using things such as on from jQuery). Another option is to add your code in the `afterRender` callback of fullpage.js

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    afterRender: function(){
       $('.element').addClass('element-animated');
    }
});
```